# Airflow API Documentation Location

Tags: airflow

I understand this is potentially a bad question but I'm still having trouble finding the information I need. What is the best way for me to see every function available to me from any airflow import? For example I have these two Airflow classes:

```
from airflow.models import Variable
environment = Variable.get("environment")

# and

from airflow import settings
session = settings.Session()
```

And I want to see what I can do with these two classes. I want to see all code possibilities so I evaluate whether or not I can use them for an issue I'm having.

Typically I would expect to find a page similar to this https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_clusters or this https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html just to serve as examples. But with Airflow all I can find is this https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables which doesn't show me everything possible for the Variable class. I've found certain files that show the code like this https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/models.html but even for that site I can't find the Variable or settings class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow API has a read-the-docs section here: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html

For example, you can see the page for Variable here: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#airflow.models.Variable

Notice the documentation is generated by Sphinx from the docstrings of the methods and some methods don't have docstrings. Compare the API reference page with the [source code](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/models.html#Variable).

Comment: That link for Variables does not list all it's methods though. For example I don't see `Variable.get("environment")`  on there and I know that's a valid function call.

Comment: That's because that reference page is auto-generated through Sphinx by pulling the docstring of each method and the method get doesn't have a docstring, see https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/models.html#Variable

Comment: That's unfortunate. So we're left having to manually fish around the Airflow code to find what we need.

Comment: @KyleBridenstine I am sure they would be happy with some PRs to [improve documentation](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#improve-documentation) ;-)

Comment: Ugh you're asking me to do my part in society? :D

Comment: @KyleBridenstine You can check how to use variables at https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#variables

Comment: Thanks @kaxil but that still doesn't show what I'm looking for which is a document that lists all Variables commands. The link you send only shows how to read a Variable not write to it. But looks like their documentation just isn't up to date with the information I'm looking for.